# Invalidating cache techniques when storing rich objects

Tags: caching

There are times when you store entire object graphs into cache, or objects with collections that make cache invalidation a little tricky.

What techniques are there to know when to invalid a cache?

For simple objects you can invalidate whenever you e.g. update/save the object, you could simply make an extra call and refresh the cache.

When you have a rich object like, for example:

```
User
  Locations
  Sales
  History
```

Now this user object will become 'dirty' whenever the user properties, or Location/Sales/History collection data is mutated.

I think one simple method would be to updated the 'modified_date' property of the user object, and maybe keep the modified_date as part of the cache key, and make a call to get the user row and then compare then pull the object graph from the cache based on the modified_date in the key:

```
user_cache_key + user.id + user.modified_date
```

The only problem with this approach is you have to make sure you update the 'modified_date' whenever any of the objects dependancies are updated.

Are there any other possible solutions to this problem?

Comment: Have you solved this? That's just what I'm thinking about. I don't modify the key, but store the `validity` time with the value. There's also an `invalidation` time and `invalidation > validity` means the entry is obsolete. The `invalidation` time of a `User` gets computed recursively as the maximum of its own and of all its contributors (`Location`, etc.). I haven't really tried it yet.